# How to use go importer

Tags: go

I have been trying to use the importer to parse the types defined in a particular package. However, the importer always return an error saying the package is not found. What mistake I am making?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/importer"
)

func main() {
    pkg, err := importer.Default().Import("github.com/onsi/ginkgo")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(pkg)
}
```

I tried to read the go importer documentation, but it provides very limited information. I also tried to use the package I am importing here, but it does not help. However, if I import a go standard package, such as “time”, I can currently import the package. Why is that?

Comment: are you trying to dynamically import during runtime ... or as below question explains are you cool with just doing import before compile time ?

Comment: Just a clarification on what I need. I am detecting package information at runtime. I also mainly use go modules rather than GOPATH.

Comment: While I think there's supposed to be a way to do this with the existing `go/importer` package which internally calls out to the `go` tool to locate the module source, I think you want to look at [`golang.org/x/tools/go/packages`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages) which is supposed to supersede the `go/importer` package.

Comment: Hi @YifanSun Can you guide me to use this package? I have tried but it returns can't find import, if I import directly the package by using import statement, I can use the struct in the package.

Answer (score 2):

Go importer will not download the package for you. You can use [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) or [go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) to handle your dependencies, but an easy fix would be downloading the package directly to your gopath using [go get](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/get/):

```
go get -u github.com/onsi/ginkgo
```

After that, go importer will work and your code output should be:

```
package ginkgo ("github.com/onsi/ginkgo")
```

[EDIT] Using Go Modules:

There's a bunch of tutorials about that, but the quick and dirty way is, on your package directory:

```
$ GO111MODULE=on go mod init
$ GO111MODULE=on go mod tidy
```

That will check your project and download all packages. To install a specific package on your `go.mod`, you can use:

```
$ go install github.com/onsi/ginkgo
```

Comment: I tried this with GOPATH and it works. So my question is how to get the same thing working with Go Modules?

Comment: There's a bunch of tutorials about that, but the quick and dirty way is, on your package directory:  
$ GO111MODULE=on go mod init  
$ GO111MODULE=on go mod tidy  
  
That will check your project and download all packages. To install a specific package on your `go.mod`, you can use:  
$ go install github.com/onsi/ginkgo

Comment: I know how to set up a go module. However, the problem is that if the package I am importing is in GOPATH, i can import it. But if the package is not in the GOPATH, the `importer` cannot find it. But since I am using GOPATH at all, I cannot get all the packages in the GOPATH.

Comment: Hmm, got it...  It's a tricky scenario... I didn't tested yet, but I presume that `go mod tidy` will cleanup ginkgo, as it's not directly imported by `import` on your code.

My last guess would be maybe vendoring your package with `$ go mod vendor`? Not sure if, similar to `tidy`, if it will not override any changes on your `go.mod` config and eliminate not "imported" packages

Comment: Yes, `go mod tidy` will remove the package which isn't imported. The old `Import` interface does not work with vendor either: `CAUTION: This interface does not support the import of locally vendored packages.`