# List all imported types given an import path

Tags: go, types

I am trying to list all imported types from a given import path at runtime. Sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/importer"
)

func main() {
    pkg, err := importer.Default().Import("github.com/aler9/goroslib/pkg/msgs/std_msgs") 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
        return
    }
    for _, declName := range pkg.Scope().Names() {
        fmt.Println(declName)
    }
}
```

This results in error:

> error: can't find import: "github.com/aler9/goroslib/pkg/msgs/std_msgs"

It is possbile to achieve what I want with Golang?

---

Note:

I am aware of the post: [How to use go importer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259230/how-to-use-go-importer)

By using `pkg, err := importer.Default().Import("github.com/aler9/goroslib")` the binary returns a few types but they are not what I want.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with `go/importer`, or even if it's possible.

However, you could, for example, use the `golang.org/x/tools/go/packages` package to load a package's AST and then traverse that tree to print out any type declarations you find.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/token"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

func main() {
    loadConfig := new(packages.Config)
    loadConfig.Mode = packages.NeedSyntax
    loadConfig.Fset = token.NewFileSet()
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(loadConfig, "encoding/json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        for _, syn := range pkg.Syntax {
            for _, dec := range syn.Decls {
                if gen, ok := dec.(*ast.GenDecl); ok && gen.Tok == token.TYPE {
                    for _, spec := range gen.Specs {
                        if ts, ok := spec.(*ast.TypeSpec); ok {
                            fmt.Println(ts.Name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE #1: The above example will print exported *and* unexported types. If you want to print exported only you can add an if condition to check for [`ts.Name.IsExported`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#Ident.IsExported).

NOTE #2: The package you want to load, if I'm not mistaken, *must* already be in your module cache because [`packages.Load`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages#Load) will not go over the network and download it if it's not there.